# The significance of modularity for all Galois representations

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-representations, elliptic-curves

On pg. 1 of the [slides of a talk](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/slides/harvard08/slides.pdf), Henri Darmon wrote:

> **Question:** What is an interesting Diophantine equation?
>
> **A “working definition”**. A Diophantine equation is interesting
>   if it reveals or suggests a rich 
>   underlying mathematical structure.

One can adopt the perspective that the interesting elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ are those that are modular and view the fact that *all* elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ are modular as being of minor significance (in the sense that if some weren't, they wouldn't be so interesting).

I realize that my raising this perspective may come across as an affront to some of the celebrated research of recent times, and would hasten to emphasize that I'm asking my questions here in good faith with a view toward learning more.

> What would we lose if we decided to
>   focus only on those Galois
>   representations that are attached to
>   automorphic forms and ignore the
>   possibility that some do not?

One thing that one would lose is Wiles' proof of Fermat's last theorem. Until recently, my attitude had been that the Frey Curve construction is a curiosity and that a "morally right" proof would come from the $abc$-conjecture applied to sufficiently large exponents together with the theory of arithmetic of cyclotomic fields to rule out the possibility of nontrivial solutions to the equations with smaller exponents. However, recently I came across slides from a [talk by Minhyong Kim](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahmki/sheffield.pdf) in which Kim wrote (pg. 29):

> The idea of encoding points into
>   'larger' geometry is a common one in
>   Diophantine geometry, as when
>   solutions
>
> $a^n + b^n = c^n$
>
> to the Fermat equation are encoded
>   into the elliptic curves
>
> $y^2 = x(x - a^n)(x + b^n)$.
>
> The geometry of the path torsor
>   $\pi_1(X(\mathbb{C}); b, x)$ is an
>   extremely canonical version of this
>   idea.

I find the idea that the Frey curve construction is canonical to be fascinating! It raises the possibility that the proof of Fermat's last theorem coming from the study of Frey equations is morally right. [**Edit:** As KristianJS aptly points out, I misread Kim's quote. So I'd recur to my remark above about my impression on what a "morally right" proof of Fermat's Last Theorem would look like.]

Anyway, I'd be very interested in further examples concerning the significance of *all* L-functions attached to Galois representations (of suitable type) being modular.

[**Added:** If I remember correctly, In ["The Map of My Life"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387797149) Shimura wrote that he was more interested in the fact that suitable cusp forms correspond to elliptic curves than in the converse. This seems relevant. However, I cannot find the quotation and may be misremembering. I would welcome a reference from anybody who remembers this.]

[**Added**: I just asked [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108846/modularity-of-higher-dimensional-abelian-varieties) that touches on material that may provide a partial answer to this question.]

Comment: This seems to suggest that the only possible rich underlying mathematical structure for a Galois representation is an automorphic one, which is of course false. There are many interesting structures in Galois representations that do not involve Langlands at all. Secondly, without proving that all Galois representation are automorphic, it can be very hard to know whether a specific individual Galois representation or family of Galois representations you care about is automorphic. There are many natural problems where one runs across a specific Galois representation or family of them.

Comment: OK, but why not separate out "questions and theorems about Galois representations that may or may not be automorphic" and "questions and theorems about automorphic Galois representations" and not worry about whether the former class of Galois representations is contained in the latter?

Comment: Just to nitpick, in your reference to Minhyong's talk, he's not saying that the Frey curve is an example of the sort of canonical association of points with the path space. He's just pointing out how associating a point with something with more structure is often useful, and that the association of a point with the etale path-space is an entirely systematic way of doing this for any scheme.

Comment: KristianJS - not a nitpick at all, thanks for catching me.

Comment: Jonah, FYI (and future reference), not a big deal, but the proper tag is "nt.number-theory", not just "number-theory". I went ahead and retagged this one, since it was already near the top. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: Thanks BR, no problem. (P.S. Do I know you in real life? Feel free to email me.)

Comment: (I don't think so, unless we met very briefly . . .)

Comment: Some people just happen to be interested in solving diophantine equations, and in particular in understanding the arithmetic of curves/arbitrary abelian varieties/you name it over arbitrary number fields. This is to name but one source of not obviously modular $L$-functions that people find interesting in their own right.

Comment: @Jonah: Because, if the former class is contained in the latter, than theorems about automorphic Galois representations are also theorems about Galois representations that may or may not be automorphic, providing new theorems about Galois representations that may or may not be automorphic.

Comment: @ Will - Yes, makes sense. I'd welcome references. Stankewicz gave one - are there others that you have in mind?

Comment: @ Alex - yes, of course you're right that if you want to understand the arithmetic of *all* elliptic curves over Q (say) then you need to prove that they're all modular.

Comment: Dear Jonah, You suggest below a perspective of throwing out Kronecker--Weber.  Of course you are free to do so, but proving reciprocity laws (quadratic reciprocity, on which Gauss focussed so much effort, and then higher reciprocity laws, on which Kummer focussed most of his work, and then non-abelian reciprocity laws, which is what you are asking about) has been a major focus of many number theorists for more than 200 years.  Also, proving a reciprocity law (i.e. establishing that a Galois representation or Diophantine equation is modular) introduces enormous extra structure and a new set ...

Comment: of tools for studying the problem.  (E.g. almost all progress on BSD so far had used modularity as an assumption.)  You may not care about BSD for elliptic curves that are not modular, but most people interested in the question regard it as a question about *all* elliptic curves over $\mathbb Q$, to which modularity provides a point of entry for solving it.  Regards, Matthew

Comment: @ Emerton: I don't understand your first comment. One doesn't need to know the Kronecker-Weber theorem to prove quadratic reciprocity, or the corresponding statement for other fields to prove higher reciprocity laws. Am I missing something? Regarding the fact that many people are interested in all elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$, of course you're right, and that gives reason for people to prove general modularity theorems. Note that in my above question I asked about what we would lose if we didn't have general modularity results. There's the tautological answer...

Comment: that we wouldn't know that all elliptic curves are modular, we wouldn't be able to prove BSD for such elliptic curves, etc. I was wondering what else we would lose. I found stankewicz's answer about Calegari's work helpful in this regard. I found the discussion of Hida families less helpful, but only because I don't know anything about the subject. I'd be interested in any other examples that you can think of, as well as examples of applications Calegari's theorem might have.

Comment: Dear Jonah, What I mean is that quadratic reciprocity is about splitting of primes in the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{\pm p}),$ and is (in my view) most naturally proved by embedding $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{\pm p})$ inside $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$.  Of course such an embedding can be constructed by Gauss sum's, but however one constructs it, one is using the philosophy of Kronecker--Weber/automorphy: we take a field for which we don't know reciprocity (the quadratic field), and place it in a context where we do have a reciprocity law (the cyclotomic field).  Modularity for elliptic curves is used in the ...  

Comment: ... same way: we start with a Diophantine equation for which we don't know reciprocity, but by writing it as a quotient of a modular curve,
for which we have rich reciprocity laws (Eichler--Shimura, Bloch--Beilinson elements, Kato's Euler systems, ...) we can prove things about the original elliptic curve.  Regards, Matthew

Comment: The proof of quadratic reciprocity that I had in mind is the same as the one that you mention. The perspective that I'm suggesting is that in this context, cyclotomic fields are the fundamental objects of study and that the the significance of quadratic reciprocity is not intrinsic, but rather that *it points toward* cyclotomic fields, the corresponding reciprocity law and the fact that the reciprocity law descends to their subfields. That quadratic reciprocity is the first reciprocity law that was observed is a historical coincidence. If the first reciprocity law to be discovered had been...

Comment: cyclotomic reciprocity then the initial focus of number theoretic research might have been on finding analogs of the cyclotomic fields rather than on starting with a field for which one knows doesn't know reciprocity and finding a field to embed it in for which one knows a reciprocity law. I'm wondering about the extent to which one might be led to the latter question by studying the former question (beyond just by asking "what about the converse?")...

Comment: The main theorems about automorphic Galois representations I was thinking about were the strong results on L-functions - analytic continuation, functional equation, etc.  In particular, modularity for all representations implies equidistribution for all representations, maybe up to some technical details. But I don't think you'd find that very convincing.

Comment: @ Will - I find the equidistribution example that you mention potentially compelling, but am unclear on how much one actually needs to deduce equidistribution. See my back and forth with Emerton under Joël's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question reminds me of a current strain of research whose starting point is Serre's conjecture, now the Khare-Wintenberger Theorem:

> any continuous odd irreducible two-dimensional Galois representation over a finite field arises from a modular form

The question one might ask is then "Where are the even Galois representations?"

The answer given (mostly by F. Calegari) is that they just don't exist when you put certain additional restrictions on your Galois representation. Suppose then that you somehow have an even two-dimensional Galois representation in your hands. Well then this Galois representation is very special in some ways that might not be apparent! You can then ask: where did this representation come from? Is it modular in some non-obvious way?

So if I were to answer your question "What would we lose if we decided to focus only on those Galois representations that are attached to automorphic forms and ignore the possibility that some do not?" I would say that you lose a lot of knowledge about what makes modular Galois representations special. In your terminology, you might lose the scope of just how interesting certain representations can be!

Comment: Thanks for highlighting Calegari's work. My main takeaway from your comment in conjunction with the introduction to Calegari's paper is that one can rule out the existence of even two dimensional Galois representations (satisfying suitable restrictions) by proving the potential modularity of Galois representations satisfying these restrictions.

Comment: I hope that somebody will eventually offer a more comprehensive answer, but I've accepted this one for now.

Comment: there are lots of even mod p galois reps (just take a totally real galois number field and an irred. 2-dimensional mod p representation of its galois group over Q), calegari's theorem is for p-adic galois reps. thus it would be better to talk about the (odd) fontaine-mazur (for GL2/Q), essentially proved by kisin and emerton, rather than serre's conjecture above.

Comment: i don't know of any equally satisfying answer as serre's conjecture for even mod p galois reps. they are not all explained by mass forms as the projective image could be very big (like PSL2(Fp)), preventing a lift to char 0. one can try to relate them to automorphic reps, or more generally mod p cohomology of arithmetic groups (which doesn't always lift to char 0), in a more indirect way by restricting to the galois group of an imaginary quadratic extension, or (as does ash et al) by adding a character.

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure I understand your question. Or rather, as I understand your question, you have already answered it. Well, you asked "what would we loose if we..." and you answered "Wiles' proof of FLT". Isn't that enough? We have developed more complicated theories for much less venerable questions!

Admitting rhetorically that it isn't enough, one can develop your answer. If we want to restrict our consideration to representation that are a priori modular, 
we would loose not only Wiles' proof of FLT, but also Wiles and others's proof of the Taniyama-Shimura-Weil conjecture (and this one has nothing to do with the Frey's curve), so we would lose the
corollary that L-functions of elliptic curves satisfy a functional equation and have an analytic extension... We would then not even be able to formulate the beautiful conjecture of
Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer! We would also loose that the symmetric powers of the representation
attached to an elliptic curve are modular. So we would lose the Sato-Tate conjecture as well.

In a word, we would loose all the Galois representations coming from algebraic geometry, because we don't know *a priori* that they are modular/automorphic. And the fact is that those representations contain a lot of deep arithmetic and geometric (if you believe to Tate's conjecture) information.

**Added:** The above is about the fact that without talking of representations that are not modular/automorphic we would lose the ability even to formulate a theorem of the form "such and such representation is modular". Here's another, different, point. We also need Galois representations that are not modular, in order to prove things about representations that are modular. I am refereeing to all the arguments of p-adic families (Hida's family, 
eigencurve, eigenvarieties) who carry at each point a Galois representation which
most of the time is **not modular**. but we need those point to give flesh to the eigenvariety whose "skeleton" is made of the modular ones. To give an early example of those techniques,
Wiles proved that a Galois representation attached to an ordinary form is ordinary (a statement purely about modular galois representation) using Hida's families, hence non-modular representations. Nowadays those techniques are ubiquitous...

Comment: Joël, *Birch and* Swinnerton-Dyer.

Comment: Sure! Edited...

Comment: (Potentially modular, I guess, for the symmetric powers of the Tate module.)

Comment: Thanks! Regarding FLT, my suggestion was that there's another, more natural proof. Regarding BSD, if one would like, one can restrict oneself to the consideration of modular elliptic curves and their arithmetic, then BSD is well formulated. If one restricts oneself to modular elliptic curves, my impression is that the analytic continuation of the symmetric power L-functions is expected to be provable by analytic means (Kim, Shahidi, etc.)...

Comment: Regarding Galois representations coming from algebraic geometry - we wouldn't lose *all* of them. Regarding the p-adic families, I'm very interested in learning more. Thanks for the references.

Comment: Dear Jonah, The Kim--Shahidi approach (which builds on an idea of Langlands) has intrinsic limitations, as far as I know (in that it can only access certain symmetric powers, not all of them).  Langlands envisions a proof of functoriality for symmetric powers (and hence analytic continuation of symmetric power $L$-functions) via trace formula methods, but the trace formula arguments (especially endoscopy) involve, as well as a lot of harmonic analysis, also the full force of class field theory (via Galois cohomology calculations).    It is hard to remove class field theory from the arguments!

Comment: @ Emerton - thanks very much for the information, this is a very good example which offers food for thought. 

Answer (score 7):

I want to make a couple of comments about the premise of this question. First, the OP asks what the consequences would be if we "focus only on those Galois representations that are attached to automorphic forms and ignore the possibility that some do not".  But of course it is certainly the case that there exist Galois representations that are not attached to automorphic forms (Galois representations that are ramified at infinitely many primes, for instance).

Second, the OP writes about "Galois representations that are attached to automorphic forms" as though this phrase is well-defined.  But do you mean the automorphic forms that conjecturally believed to have Galois representations attached to them, or the automorphic forms that are currently known to have Galois representations attached to them?  The latter is a (growing but proper!) subset of the former; and note again that the former is not "all automorphic forms" (see e.g. the paper of Buzzard-Gee in the 2011 LMS Durham Symposium).

So, there's a conjectural map from (some) automorphic forms to (some) Galois representations, and this has been understood for decades to have significant arithmetic consequences for representations in the image of the map.  The most generous way I can think to interpret the question is "What would happen if we satisfied ourselves with statements of the form "If $\rho$ is in the image of this map in an instance where the map has been constructed...", without attempting to characterize the image in some easily checkable way?", and the answer is simply that we would lose most or all of the arithmetic consequences.

Comment: Regarding your first question - Yes, I know that not all Galois representations are attached to automorphic forms. Regarding your other two questions: perhaps I should have phrased by question more carefully. I had in mind the correspondence between elliptic curves over Q and weight 2 cusp eigenforms for congruence subgroups of SL(2, Z) in particular, but also meant to indicate that I'm interested in the question in general generality as well.

Comment: When you say "we would lose most or all of the arithmetic consequences," which arithmetic consequences do you have in mind?

Answer (score 5):

You would lose all the p-adic families of Galois representations, that are necessary to prove properties of the modular ones.   Hida's family was necessary for the proof ofMTT, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What's MTT?

Comment: MTT = Mazur–Tate–Teitelbaum. A conjecture about L-invariants proved by Greenberg and Stevens using Hida families.

Answer (score 3):

Proving modularity of finite image Galois representations seems to be the most feasible way of proving the [Artin conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_conjecture_%28L-functions%29). In fact, this was one of Langlands' original motivations.

Comment: This is true, but in a certain sense begs the question. Why not restrict one's consideration to Galois representations satisfying the Artin conjecture from the outset?

Comment: I suppose you could, but I think it would not be in the spirit of non-abelian class field theory. For $GL_{1}$, this is like asking "why bother studying all abelian extensions when we can just study the cyclotomic extensions?" You'd be throwing out Kronecker-Weber! 

Comment: I realize that this probably seems bizarre, but yes, I'm suggesting a perspective that throws out Kronecker-Weber. One has a beautiful uniform construction of a collection of abelian extensions of Q of varying conductors and can deduce a reciprocity law for each (relative to Q) which descends to all subfields of such extensions. Does it matter that there are no others? One has a beautiful uniform construction of unramified abelian extensions of imaginary quadratic fields with degree equal to the class number of the underlying field. Does it matter that there are no others?

Comment: ...For an analogy, it's arguable that Monstrous Moonshine is more interesting than the fact that the Monster Group is the last sporadic finite group. As a disclaimer, I don't mean to suggest that I have any *confidence* in the soundness of perspective that I'm suggesting - it's just a thought experiment.

Comment: One might as well throw out all theorems containing a universal quantifier.

Comment: Granting that Kronecker-Weber *is* a theorem, which shows that a particular way of creating abelian extensions of the rationals contains all examples, what is the motivation for wanting to get by without that theorem? Similarly, over a number field $K$, the ray class fields over $K$ are finite abelian extensions and (with hard work) it turns out any finite abelian extension of $K$ is inside one of these. Why would you *prefer* to speak of "extensions of $K$ inside ray class fields over $K$" instead of "finite abelian extensions of $K$", which is both cleaner and more conceptual? 

Comment: This topic reminds me of a postdoc comment in grad school: in harmonic analysis, maybe one could go through all theorems in the subject and replace the hypothesis "locally compact Hausdorff topological group" with "locally cpt Hausdorff top. group that has a Haar measure", thus avoiding the proof by Zorn's lemma that every locally cpt Hausdorff top. group *has* a Haar measure; there'd be no practical loss since the groups that you often really care about have a construction of a Haar measure that doesn't need Zorn's lemma. But then the *true scope* of harmonic analysis would be tossed out.

Comment: @ KConrad: I agree that "finite abelian extensions" is cleaner and more conceptual. Perhaps I should have given more context. I asked a distinguished mathematician about the existence of "natural" proofs of CFT and he said that they should come from a solution to Hilbert's 12th problem. I responded by saying that that would take care of the existence of class fields, but that it wouldn't furnish a proof that the class fields exhaust all abelian extensions. For example, complex multiplication doesn't seem to help with showing that e.g. every unramified abelian extension of an imaginary...

Comment: quadratic field is contained in its Hilbert class field ( http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100276/can-one-prove-complex-multiplication-without-assuming-cft ). He responded by saying that he agrees, but that he thinks that perhaps it's too much to hope for natural proofs of the exhaustivity of the class fields, just as it may be too much to hope for a natural proof of the classification of finite simple groups, of simple Lie algebras, etc. This was very interesting to me as it suggested that maybe the "right" perspective is that class fields are the natural objects of consideration rather...

Comment: than abelian extensions. To see why it might be better to focus on a subclass of objects that has a less clean definition than the superclass, consider Hilbert's 10th problem. The class "all diophantine equations" has a simpler description than "homogeneous diophantine equations specifying abelian varieties" but the class "all diophantine equations" is clearly the wrong object of focus insofar as the problem of finding solutions to all of them is known to be undecidable. Aside from the aforementioned conversation with the distinguished mathematician, the other thing that got me thinking in...

Comment: this direction is my memories of Shimura's comments from "The Map of My Life." I can't find all of the relevant quotations, but one of them is: “Suppose we have a mathematical object A and we easily see that A satisﬁes a certain set of properties P. It often happens that it is natural to conjecture that a mathematical object with properties P must be A, but it is difficult to prove it. Then many mathematicians consider the solution of that problem a great achievement. I said “many,” but  “almost all” is often more appropriate. I think this type of thought is fundamentally wrong...


Comment: There are many cases. If A is a collection of many objects with the said properties, the situation is different. If A is absolutely a 
single object, then the solution adds no new knowledge, as in the case of Hilbert’s foundation of geometry. The matter would be different if there were some interesting applications, but in most 
cases we ﬁnd no applications." Shimura's book contains many controversial statements that differ from the consensus of other great mathematicians, but even so, his stature is such that I think such this particular comment deserve consideration.

Comment: In line with Shimura's comment about interesting applications, I'm interested in hearing about *applications* of the non-existence of abelian extensions other than class fields, the modularity of *all* elliptic curves over Q, etc. I realize that I'm in pernicious territory here insofar as saying "I prefer A over B" can carry the connotation "people who are working on B aren't doing valuable work." I believe in aesthetic tolerance (as Lang described in his letter to Mordell) and that the work that other people find aesthetically pleasing is valuable independently of whether I find it so...

Comment: My reasons for pursuing this line of discussion are (a) to learn more about applications (b) to suggest a perspective that may not have occurred to certain people who would find it appealing.

Comment: @ KConrad : I'm not sure if I understand your comment - it sounds like you're saying that the existence of a Haar measure on locally compact Hausdorff topological groups is intrinsically interesting to you. Is this right? My own inclination is in the direction of the postdoc who you mention. There are two reasons for this - one is that I'm sympathetic to Shimura's comment that I quoted above, and the other is that I have constructivist leanings *ala* Kronecker.

Comment: Dear Jonah, The statement that all abelian extensions are class fields  is encapsulated in Artin's reciprocity law.  This generalizes and synthesizes a huge amount of earlier number theory (including much of the number-theoretic work of Gauss, Eisenstein, and Kummer).  It has many applications.  I find your perspective interesting to think about, but I'm mentioning this just so you have a sense of what's at stake in the discussion.  Incidentally, in modern proofs of class field theory, the proof that all abelian extensions are class fields comes before the proof that class field exist and ...

Comment: are abelian.  Note that it is not clear a priori that class fields are abelian (and one could imagine constructing them but not knowing directly that they are abelian).  The interrelationship of the various concepts we're discussing is intricate and rich, and reciprocity laws (both the explicit ones for cyclotomic fields and modular curves, and the more mysterious ones provided by class field theory and the modularity theorem for eliptic curves) are a source of fascination for many.  Best wishes, 

Comment: @Jonah: I didn't mean to suggest that I find the existence of Haar measure interesting on its own. I was comparing the distinction "subfields of cyclotomic fields" vs. "finite abelian extensions of Q" with "locally compact groups admitting a Haar measure" vs. "locally compact groups" (include Hausdorff condition both times). Things of the first type are trivially of the second type, but it sure is *nice* that the things of the second type are also of the first type. As a simple example of what you gain, if you show a Galois extension of Q is abelian then Kron-Web theorem tells you [contd]

Comment: that the splitting law in that extension will be describable by congruence conditions. Do you agree that is nice? Isn't it *nice* that the *hard* property that an odd prime has the form $x^2 + y^2$ is the *same* as being 1 mod 4, which is *easy* to check? Abelian extensions can arise in nature not directly as a subfield of some cyclotomic field, so the KW theorem is telling you something valuable about that field (e.g., by KW its zeta-function decomposes as a product of Dirichlet L-functions, which a priori is not obvious at all).